# Clearing undefined value in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function test()
{
    var testcodevalue = document.getElementById("testcode").value;
    var testcodetext = document.getElementById("testcode").text;    
    if(testcodetext == undefined)
    {
       formObject.testcode.value = "";
       formObject.testcode.text = "";
    }
}
```

In the above script `onload` I get value of `testcodevalue` as object and `testccodetext` as `undefined`. The `testcode.value` I am setting into a textbox.The issue is everytime `onload` I get `testcodetext` as `undefined` and the same value is set in textbox. How do I clear this?

Comment: what type of element is `testcode`?

Comment: Text box element in form.In some flows i get text value.In tat case proper text value is set.but else where onload of page i get  undefined as well.

Comment: In that case i just empty string as value and undefined is set in my text box

Comment: There is no text attribute on a textbox that I know of: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html I am not sure what you are expecting it to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use typeof to check if it is undefined:

```
function test()
        {

                var testcodevalue = document.getElementById("testcode").value;
                var testcodetext = document.getElementById("testcode").text;    
                if(typeof testcodetext === "undefined")
                {
                   formObject.testcode.value =  "";
                   formObject.testcode.text =   "";
                 }
        }
```

Comment: the check is still the same thing as what the OP had.

Comment: Could you do a jsfiddle of your full code so I can see what exactly is going on and what you're trying to do?

Comment: epascarello - you are incorrect... typeof testcodetext === "undefined" would return true if testcodetext is undefined.  the OP had testcodetext == undefined which would return an error of testcodetext is undefined instead.  But I've found the real problem here.  The problem is not that the element or variable is actually undefined.  It actually has nothing to do with this problem.  Thanks for being so quick to downvote before even giving me a chance to respond to the OP.

Comment: @cxyz - first thing that I see is that the variable sel is assigned to an element.  The element does not have a length attribute.  Second - it's a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish, but your beginning value of carrierId is blank therefore nothing inside of your for loop is being hit...  Could you check this and make any corrections that I may be mistaken on?  I've created elements based on how I assume this may be intended to work.  http://jsfiddle.net/hdrenollet/KSuGk/2/

Comment: @HowardRenollet jsfiddle.net/hdrenollet/KSuGk/2 pls check updated fiddle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40277/discussion-between-cxyz-and-howard-renollet)

Comment: The solution for this was to do a null check before setting values